# Want to credit amount straight to merchant account through paypal

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal, payment-processing

I have done a paypal integration using 'Website Payments Standard' and 'Buy Now Button' in php.

Current behaviour:
When the buyer buys an item and pays for it, the amount gets stored in the merchant account. The merchant has to manually login to paypal account and transfer the amount to his bank account.

Instead we want to have it like, when the buyer successfully makes payment the amount has to automatically go through paypal to merchant's bank account? Is it possible to configure that?

Thanks,
Vincy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call paypal and inquire about a feature called Auto-Sweep. This is not an option by default and you must be qualified for it.